# CSS display divs below each other after screen gets to 700px

Tags: php, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard_wrap">

<div>orders</div>

<div>porting</div>

<div>contact</div>

</div>
```

that displays 3 divs, here is the CSS:

```
.dashboard_wrap {
    padding:10px;
}
.dashboard_wrap div {
    border-left:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    width: 50%;
    height:200px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    float: left;
}
.dashboard_clear:after {
   content: "";
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
    div.wrap div {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

I am using PHP so only certain users can see certain divs. If a user can only see the first 2 divs, how can i make them 50% each rather than 40%?

Comment: You can use javascript or jquery.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you hiding the div or is PHP preventing it from even showing in the HTML?

Comment: the if statement in PHP is preventing the div from showing at all

Comment: your selection in the media query should be `.dashboard_wrap div`, and your media query uses `max-width` which means that those properties will apply when the screen is at or below that pixel size - in your case 700px. See this fiddle to see if this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/3f49s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use php or javascript for this. You can use basic html and css for this.
You can check the html fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/4WaX4/1/

All the css which you need is this:

```
.dashboard_wrap {
    display:table;
    min-width:500px;
    background:#00ff00;
}
.dashboard_items {
    display:table-row;
}
.dashboard_items div{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
@media all and (max-width: 700px) {
    div.dashboard_items div {
        width: 100%;
        display:block;
    }
}
```

And the html looks as follows:

```
<div class="dashboard_wrap">
    <div class="dashboard_items">
        <div>orders</div>

        <div>porting</div>        
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard_wrap">
    <div class="dashboard_items">

        <div>orders</div>

        <div>porting</div>

        <div>contact</div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Very simpel and quick. When you resize the result window in jsfiddle you see that the divs become 100% relative to the outer div (500px).

I hope this is the solution youre looking for...

Comment: I dont see why you coudn't just use the :nth-child(3) (or the div you want to hide) selector to hide the last div (display none) if (max-width: 700px)

Comment: Because the question was how make columns width 100/number of items. Read the question again.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the class of the wrapper based on the number of items inside.
CSS classes for each variant will handle the style automatically.

If however the number of divs can extend beyond expected numbers, then dynamic inline styles may be your solution.

```
<div class="dashboard_wrap has3">

    <div>orders</div>

    <div>porting</div>

    <div>contact</div>

</div>

<div class="dashboard_wrap has2">

    <div>orders</div>

    <div>porting</div>

</div>

<style>
.dashboard_wrap div {
    border-left:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    height:200px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    float: left;
}

.dashboard_wrap.has2 div {
    width: 50%;
}

.dashboard_wrap.has3 div {
    width: 33%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page gets rendered, only two divs will be visible. What you need to do is use a client-based language i.e. javascript or jQuery, to manipulate what is visible on screen.

Use a simple check to see what divs are visible or use php to generate a value which you can hide in the page to make it easier to resize the divs like:

```
<input type='hidden' id='divs_visible' value='" . $divs_visible ."' />
```

then using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var divsvis = $("#divs_visible").val();

   if(divsvis == 2)
   {
      // resize the divs
   }

});
```

EDIT

You can also render all the divs, then using jQuery and the value you've placed in the hidden input, you can simply hide the div you do not need with:

```
$("#div_to_be_hidden").hide();
```